# How to get sum of absolute value of columns of data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables

I have below code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here         
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
            dt.Columns["Column1"].DataType = typeof(Int32);
            dt.Rows.Add(1);
            dt.Rows.Add(2);
            dt.Rows.Add(-1);
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(Column1)", "Column1 < 10"));
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

It will give op as 2, both +ve no will be added and -ve one will be subtracted . I need 4 as OP. I mean abs value of all. How to do it?

Comment: are you looking for [Math.Abs](https://www.dotnetperls.com/math-abs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. Imagine that you have

```
 -20, 1, -2
```

In case you want to have `3 == 1 + |-2|` (notice that `-20` is *ruled out* and we're filtering by *absolute values*) you can put *Linq* which looks quite direct

```
var result = dt
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(record => Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(record["Column1"])))
  .Where(item => item < 10)
  .Sum();
```

In case you want `23 == |-20| + 1 + |-2|` (notice that `-20` is *preserved* and we're filtering by *values*) you can put

```
var result = dt
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(record => Convert.ToInt32(record["Column1"]))
  .Where(item => item < 10)
  .Sum(item => Math.Abs(item));
```

**Edit:** in complex queries (see comments below) I suggest using *anonymous class*:

```
var result = dt
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(record => new {
     Column1 = Convert.ToInt32(record["Column1"]),
     Column2 = Convert.ToString(record["Column2"]) }) 
  .Where(item => item.Column2 == "A" || item.Column2 == "B")
  .Where(item => item.Column1 < 10) 
  .Sum(item => Math.Abs(item.Column1));
```

Comment: Actually I have a bit more complex situation like below                                      
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
            dt.Columns["Column1"].DataType = typeof(Int32);
            dt.Columns["Column2"].DataType = typeof(string);
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "A");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "B");
            dt.Rows.Add(-1, "A");
            dt.Rows.Add(5, "E");
 
            int result = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(Column1)", "Column2 = 'A' OR Column2 = 'b' "));

Comment: Can you help here

Comment: @user1926138: I suggest using *anonymous class* for the complex queries (see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ

```
var yourSum =dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where( y => y.Field<int>( "Column1" )  < 10 )
    .Sum( x => x.Field<int>( "Column1" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ for this.

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["Column1"]) < 10)
                .Sum(x => Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(x["Column1"])));
```